# Tizen Galaxy Active 2 - Sign and build with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to push an app I built with .net in visual studio 2017 (Windows 10) to my galaxy active watch.

No matter what I do, it says built with default certificates.

[image: output]

I set up my Samsung certificate with Certificate Manager [image: Cert]

In VS, I connected my credentials also (Tools > Options > Tizen)
[image: tools]

And I have the proper extension from Package Manager installed
[image: Package Manager]

I rebuilt the project and also tried form the CLI with no success. I am getting this error (from CMD)
[image: CLI]
and this one (from VS)

[image: VS error]

What did I miss?

Comment: I don't have a solution but here's some tip: The default signed TPK can be signed again with the current active or a specific profile using Tizen CLI's package command (`tizen-studio/tools/ide/bin/tizen package -- [path to tpk]`).

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem, did you found any solution?

Comment: @jonathana I updated to VS 2018, and then cleared the build before pushing it again. I actually emailed you a while back... שלחתי לך מייל

Comment: sometimes it fixes itself when you restart the Sdb from the menu.

Comment: They said to use Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to delete any certificates made via the Tizen Certificate Manager.
Make a new certificate and pick "Samsung", not "Tizen".

[image: tizen and samsung certs]

Then to jump back into Visual Studio 2017 (it didn't sign with the right certificates on 2019 for me). Next, click on the "Tools" menu and click "Options".

[image: vs settings]

Here, I selected "Direct Registration", then I manually added the author, distributor certificates and passwords... and now I can debug apps with a physical device and no problems.

[image: vs settings tizen]

Answer (score 1):

check "Sign the .TPK file using the following option"

screenshot: options/tizen - checkbox:
[image: screenshot: options/tizen - checkbox]

it worked for me